# How to load extension attribute when an order is loaded using the OrderRepositoryInterface?

Tags: magento2

I am suppose to:

1. Load extension attribute when an order is loaded using the OrderRepositoryInterface.
2. Implement functionality to save extension attribute data when an order is saved using the OrderRepositoryInterface.

I am confused with how to do this. How do I do this the right way?

Comment: For proper answer, please clarify what are you mean under first question. I think you can use entity repository or `load` method for load related entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For partial save order attribute(s) I suggest to use following logic

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Sales\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;

class OrderManagementInterfacePlugin
{
    /**
     * @var OrderResource
     */
    protected $orderResource;

    public function __construct(
        OrderResource $orderResource
    ) {
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
    }

    public function afterPlace(
        OrderManagementInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $result,
        OrderInterface $order
    ): OrderInterface {
        $order->setData('some_attribute', 'value');
        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'some_attribute');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

You can use array for list of attributes in `saveAttribute` method